# alternative for "text/x-moz-url" in Chrome / IE 10/Edge in Event.dataTransfer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, cross-browser

I'm creating a little drag'n'drop directive for angular which detects URLs dragged from another browser window/tab and just discovered it is possible to also read the original anchor Text with this property:

`xMozUrl = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/x-moz-url');`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Recommended_Drag_Types#link

This seems very handy because I can display the link Text

Is there a (bleeding edge) altnernative to Mozilla's custom `Event.dataTransfer` property on retrieving the actual Link-Text from a dragged anchor? I couldn't find anything on the docs. IE 10/11/Edge is also very appreciated.

For some context, this is the currently the whole 'drop' listener:

```
$document.bind("drop", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  if (event.target == target || event.target.parentNode == target) {
    try {
      var url, 
          linkText = '',
          xMozUrl = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/x-moz-url');

      if (xMozUrl.length > 0) {
        // mozilla also sends the link text so we can extract some kind of 'title'
        var uriParts = xMozUrl.split("\n");
        url          = uriParts[0];
        linkText     = uriParts[1];
      } else {
        // should return the first valid URL found in dataTransfer
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Recommended_Drag_Types#link
        url   = event.dataTransfer.getData('URL').toString();
        title = '';
      }

      if (url.length > 0) {
        $scope.url = url;
        $scope.$emit('drag-link:drag:drop', {
          url   : url,
          title : linkText
        });
      }

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("drop", event, event.target, event.toElement, $elem);
  }
});
```

**Edit**

Just found out by testing that IE 10,11 don't support dragging an anchor to an open Page at all. On 10/11 a the URL is just opened as if there were not event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

Chrome appears to support the 'text/x-moz-url' format.

In the case of EDGE, there is a format called "`UserActivityJsonArray`". This a JSON object with 'title' and 'uri'. This appears to be a recent developement (see: [Windows 10 SDK Preview Build 17125](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/03/30/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-17125/)). Whereas I have yet to find anything for IE10/11.